# Discord.js V14 not sending image

Tags: javascript, canvas, discord.js

I made a profile command on canvas, but the image is not sending in Discord.js v14 and there is no error in the console, does anyone know what happened?

Profile.js

```js
const discord = require('discord.js')
const Canvas = require('canvas')
const { fillTextWithTwemoji } = require('node-canvas-with-twemoji-and-discord-emoji');
const { registerFont } = require('canvas')
registerFont('././helsinki.ttf', { family: 'helsinki' })
registerFont('././bold.ttf', { family: 'bold' })
const config = require('../../config.json');
const db = require("quick.db")
module.exports = {

    name: "perfil",
    description : "Veja o perfil de alguém!",
    type: discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
options: [
        {
            name: "user",
            description: "O usuário que quer ver o perfil",
            type: discord.ApplicationCommandOptionType.User,
            required: true
        
    },
    ],
        run : async (client, interaction, args) => {
          const canvas = Canvas.createCanvas(850, 550)
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")


let user = interaction.options.getUser('user')
//pega o sobremim do comando de sobremim, que eu tambem deixei junto com esse codigo la no servidor
  let carteira = db.get(`carteira_${user.id}`);
                  if (carteira === null) carteira = 0;

//pega o avatar
// let avatar = user.avatarURL({ dynamic: true, format: "png", size: 1024 });
          
let avatar = await Canvas.loadImage("https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/" + user.id + "/" > + user.avatar + ".png");
    // a imagem de fundo, (wallpaper)
          let imagem = db.get(`imagem_${user.id}`)
  if(!imagem) imagem = `https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553631310942210/983425184172224654/1654537185896.png`
   const fundo = await 

    Canvas.loadImage(`${imagem}`)
    ctx.drawImage(fundo, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)


// o layout, a imagem onde fica as demarcaçoes dos lugares dos textos (é só abrir esse link ae embaixo que tu vai entender)
const layout = await 
    Canvas.loadImage("https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/980553632116269080/1002647753748398110/1659120241875.png")
    ctx.drawImage(layout, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
const member = client.guilds.cache.get('980553630480474232').members.cache.get(interaction.user.id); 
             ctx.font = '20px helsinki';
ctx.fillStyle = '#F8F8F8';

              await  fillTextWithTwemoji(ctx, `${carteira}`, 500, 107)
       
// escreve o nome da pessoa
ctx.font = '30px helsinki';
ctx.fillStyle = '#F8F8F8';
//ctx.fillText(`${user.username}`, 340, 73)
              await  fillTextWithTwemoji(ctx, `${user.username}`, 340, 73); 
//Jaypcoins
  
// cria uma mascara redonda pra imagem de avatar
ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(723, 108, 94, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
      ctx.closePath();
      ctx.clip();
 
     // coloca o avatar do user na imagem
    const TargetAvatar = await Canvas.loadImage(`${avatar}`)
    ctx.drawImage(TargetAvatar, 628, 12, 193, 193)
    const attachment = new Discord.AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(), {name: 'perfil.png'}) 
        return interaction.reply({content: `${interaction.user}`, files: [attachment]})
      
    }
}
```

I don't know why this goes, but I've seen it in the discord.js guide and I didn't see the error, I don't know if the canvas is not compatible but this discord.js is harder for me to understand

Answer (score 0):

Edit Reply to this

```js
const attachment = new Discord.AttachmentBuilder(canvas.toBuffer(),'profile.png');

return interaction.reply({
    files: [{
        attachment: attachment
    }],
    content:`${interaction.user}`,
});
```

Comment: edit attachment: to "attachment"